# How to save a file from a web service response in java?

Tags: java, web-services, sap-ariba

I have been successful in calling an SAP Ariba web service.  However, the response includes a zip file which I have not been able to figure out how to save.  Here is a snippet of the code I have in place to call the web service:

```
//Code to make a webservice HTTP request
URL url = new URL(strEndPoint);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream out = null;
InputStreamReader isr = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[strXMLInput.length()];
buffer = strXMLInput.getBytes();
bout.write(buffer);
byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();
  
// Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(b.length));
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
   
//Optional: set your action
//httpConn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", strEndPoint);
httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
httpConn.setDoInput(true);
out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
   
// write the content of the request to the outputstream of the HTTP Connection.
out.write(b);
out.close();

// read the response.
isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
in = new BufferedReader(isr);

// write the SOAP message response to a String.
while ((strResponse = in.readLine()) != null) 
{
  strResponseOut = strResponseOut + strResponse + "\n";
}
```

Appreciate any guidance on how to save the file from the web service response in Java.

EDIT (author comments merged): I end up with the output zip file is invalid. I suspect it is because the output is in XML format (reference below for example of response). I need to somehow parse the XML and then just save out the ZIP content.

```
<soap:Body>
  <ContractHeaderExportReply xmlns="urn:Ariba:Sourcing:vrealm_2412">
    <WSContractHeaderExportOutputBean_Item>
      <item>
        <Status>0</Status>
        <ErrorMessage>The web service method is successfully executed.</ErrorMessage>
        <HeaderExportFile>zip file content is here....</HeaderExportFile>
        <MimeType>application/zip</MimeType>
      </item>
    </WSContractHeaderExportOutputBean_Item>
  </ContractHeaderExportReply>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: Since you have an InputStream you can use 'Files.copy(InputStream in, Path target)'

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I end up with the output zip file is invalid.  I suspect it is because the output is in xml format (reference below for example of response).  I need to somehow parse the xml and then just save out the zip content.  Any additional help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: <soap:Body>
      <ContractHeaderExportReply xmlns="urn:Ariba:Sourcing:vrealm_2412">
         <WSContractHeaderExportOutputBean_Item>
            <item>
               <Status>0</Status>
               <ErrorMessage>The web service method is successfully executed.</ErrorMessage>
               <HeaderExportFile>zip file content is here....</HeaderExportFile>
               <MimeType>application/zip</MimeType>
            </item>
         </WSContractHeaderExportOutputBean_Item>
      </ContractHeaderExportReply>
   </soap:Body>